# Width change on hover on every link than the hovered one

Tags: html, css

As the topic said. I want the hovered one to change his `width`. But it appears that every list element changes his `width`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/JjMfU/)

Its seems easy, but i dont get it. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: When u change the `width` at  `#nav li a:hover {` to `background-color: #555;`
It works fine. Really confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't affect other elements, it just moves them. **[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/JjMfU/7/)**.

---

**Solution:** Add `margin-left: -30px;`. That will fix other elements.
Why 30px? 30px is the difference between old and new width (90 and 120px).

```css
#nav li a:hover {
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjMfU/11/)**

Comment: I'd say it's a workaround, and not a solution... If the user changes any of the widths they'll have to recalculate. Kinda not serious :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what is actually happening here: the width is changed only on a current link, not on all of them: http://jsfiddle.net/JjMfU/15/

You need to tackle a different issue - simply having the links on the right side always - which is done by floating them to the right. Notice I added `overflow: hidden` on `li` to deal with floats, other methods exist too.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/JjMfU/20/